# Postgresql - slow extract metadata when there are many schemas in the same database

Tags: postgresql, database-metadata

I have a database with 40 schemas, all must have exactly the same metadata.
I made a Java program to compare metadatas.
It works fine and fast when I test in a database with 2/3 schemas only.
But, when I run the program in production with 40 schemas, it is very slow
to extract each metadata.
Is there some PG utility or command to become faster extracting metadatas
in this cenario with so many schemas?
I use PG 9.6.6.

Comment: 40 schemas is not a very large amount, but you haven't given details to say much more

Comment: 1. apparently your java code is not optimal. 2 best tool to query metadata is SQL language 3. slow/not slow are just words - define measurable values 4. metadata is to broad - define what you need. 5. to get schema structure people use `pg_dump -s`